# What is targetPath in flutter_image_compress?

Tags: flutter

## **How to fix this error**

I am trying to reduce the size of an image file and here i use flutter_image_compress

[image]

```
  Future<File> compressFile(File file) async {
    var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
      file.absolute.path,
      file.absolute.path,
      quality: 66,
    );
    return result!;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**compressAndGetFile** takes a String path and a String targetPath. They must be different or you'll have an error.
try this :

```
final file = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);

var fileFromImage = File(file.path);
var basename = path.basenameWithoutExtension(fileFromImage.path);
var pathString = fileFromImage.path.split(path.basename(fileFromImage.path))[0];
  
var pathStringWithExtension = "$pathString${basename}_image.jpg";

 Future<File> compressFile(File file) async {
    var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
      file.absolute.path,
      pathStringWithExtension,
      quality: 66,
    );
    return result!;
  }
```

Also make sure you added **flutter_image_compress** to your **pubspec.yaml**